# Rxjs filter shiftKey

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I am looking in to sample which has this filter:

```
Observable.fromEvent(this.getNativeElement(this.btn), 'click')
      .filter(event => event.shiftKey)
      .map(event => 'Beast Mode Activated!!!')
      .subscribe(message => this.message = message);
```

This one referencing `"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.5"`

In my project I am getting an error:

`[ts] Property 'shiftKey' does not exist on type '{}'. any`

I am referencing `"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12"`

I've got same error in both cases.

that is what I've got in imports:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there's no type information on `event`

```
.filter(event => event.shiftKey)
```

it is just treated as `{}` type. You can "cast" it or specify a type

```
.filter((event: any) =>
.filter((event: ExpectedEventType) =>
.filter(event => (<any>event).shiftKey)
```

Any of these should work. With the `ExpectedEventType`, it should be replace with the actual type of event. This is only if you care for strong typing. If that's not a concern, using `any` should be fine.

Comment: now I have to put `.filter(event => (<any>event).shiftKey)` which is looking a bit wired. Is there any way to keep `.filter(event => event.shiftKey)`?

Comment: It's TypeScript compilation error. AFAIK, there is no way. Even if there was a way to suppress it, why would you want to? Just use the type `(event: any)` if you want a little cleaner look

Comment: OK I see. but how would u use `(event: any)` ? Could you provide a sample

Comment: Look at my post

Comment: OK got that. Just was being confused a bit by `.filter((event: any) =>` isteard of `.filter((event: any) => event.shiftKey)`